# How to pass properties files to Jmeter server in distributed setup

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have Jmeter distributed setup (One client and one server).

In single jmeter instance I'm using the below command to execute jmeter with a properties file that will pass the user defined variables to my test script

```
/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter -p reco.properties -n -t Performance.jmx -l test2server.csv
```

When I tried to use the same command including the server configurations I noticed that the values defined in my "**reco.properties**" are not picked at the test execution.

Instead I need to pass all the variables with "-G" argument. Ex:

```
/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter -GENV=test -n -t Performance.jmx -l test2server.csv
```

is it possible that I can pass all variables in a properties file for Jmeter Server as I do in the normal execution with "-p"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html):

> If the test uses any data files, **note that these are not sent across by the client so make sure that these are available in the appropriate directory on each server**. If necessary you can define different values for properties by editing the user.properties or system.properties files on each server.

So currently as per [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities) this is not supported, you either need to pass the properties one-by-one like `-Gprop1=value1 -Gprop2=value2` or to copy the .properties file to all the slave machines

The limitation can be also worked around via getting the properties from a dataabse using [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler or with plugins like [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) or [Redis Data Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/)

If you do believe that the feature is essential you can try raising an enhancement request in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)